# How can I type a Formula in a textbox and get it calculated (VBA)?

Tags: vba, textbox, formula, equation

I would like to calculate something with the given columns in an excel sheet

[image]

```
    'Find last column in the excel sheet "lstColumn is the variable in the sub procedure FindeLetzteSpalte"
    Call FindeLetzteSpalte
    'Find last row in the excel sheet "lstRow is the variable in the sub procedure FindeLetzteZeile"
    Call FindeLetzteZeile

    Dim KanalNamenArray() As String
    Dim cKN As Integer

    'Write all channels ("Time Axis" to "Channel F") in an Array
    ReDim KanalNamenArray(1 To lstColumn)
    For cKN = 1 To lstColumn
        KanalNamenArray(cKN) = Cells(1, cKN)
    Next cKN

    'cKN gives me the Column-Index for each channel ("Time Axis" to "Channel F") in the sheet
    '***************
    Dim sentence        As String
    Dim cntForF         As Long
    Dim cntIntern       As Long
    Dim hasWord         As Boolean
    Dim ResultFormula As Long
    Dim InputVarIndex(1 To 100) As Integer

    cntIntern = 0

    'Example sentence (Equation which I want to type in the textbox shown in the picture attached)
    sentence = "Date + Channel F"

    For cntForF = LBound(KanalNamenArray) To UBound(KanalNamenArray)
        If InStr(1, sentence, Trim(KanalNamenArray(cntForF))) Then
            hasWord = True

            'cntForF gives me the Column-Index of "Date" and "Channel F" from the variable sentence
            InputVarIndex(cntIntern) = cntForF
        End If
    Next cntForF
```

So I am able to find the Column-Index of the channels which are written in the sentence-variable.

The next thing would be to calculate every row of column Date and column Channel F 
(like "Date + Channel F")

But I have no clue how to do that

basically i want to create another channel which can be calculated with the current available channels and add the new channel next to the last column.

Something like "Channel G" = "Time Axis" + "Channel F"

i would appreciate if anyone could give me an idea. I'm also willing to accept a complete different way of thinking.

Comment: I would not dare to say I understood... So, do you need to take the date from Column 'Date'  having format "dd.mm.yyyy", add the time from F:F column and transform the format of result in something like "dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss"?

Comment: If yes, what 13.35 (from column F:F) means? 13:35 hour, or a kind of transforming the hour in decimal?

Comment: Create [a table](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-and-format-tables-e81aa349-b006-4f8a-9806-5af9df0ac664) around the A1:I14 range. When you need another calculated column, "Insert a column to the right" in that table and [enter a formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/using-structured-references-with-excel-tables-f5ed2452-2337-4f71-bed3-c8ae6d2b276e) in the terms of column headers (e.g. `=[@[Date]] + [@[Channel F]]`).